# jaxb prefix ns2 in root xml element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an issue.
I want to create sitemap, but on the root element i have `<ns2:urlset>`.

I want to remove `ns2`, so i've created package-info:

```
    @XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.something.com/something",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package app.sitemaps;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

And i have two classes to generate sitemap:

```
    package app.sitemaps;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
;



@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset", namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")
public class XmlUrlSet {

    @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "url", type = XmlUrl.class)})
    private Collection<XmlUrl> xmlUrls = new ArrayList<XmlUrl>();

    public void addUrl(XmlUrl xmlUrl) {
        xmlUrls.add(xmlUrl);
    }

    public Collection<XmlUrl> getXmlUrls() {
        return xmlUrls;
    }

}
```

AND

```
package app.sitemaps;


import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



@XmlAccessorType(value = XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "url")
public class XmlUrl {

    public enum Priority {
        HIGH("1.0"), MEDIUM("0.5");

        private String value;

        Priority(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement
    private String loc;

    @XmlElement
    private String lastmod = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

    @XmlElement
    private String changefreq = "daily";

    @XmlElement
    private String priority;

    public XmlUrl() {
    }

    public XmlUrl(String loc, Priority priority) {
        this.loc = loc;
        this.priority = priority.getValue();
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public String getChangefreq() {
        return changefreq;
    }

    public String getLastmod() {
        return lastmod;
    }

}
```

Results:

```
  <ns2:urlset>
<url>
<loc>http://www......</loc>
<lastmod>2015-10-19</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
</ns2:urlset>
```

Comment: Ok, i've made it - the namespace in package-info is the key - it should be: namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",

Comment: I think that you should use `XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED`